# Java Streams API summing Lists at index

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i would like to know if there is a more efficient way to sum all tree lists - summing their values at the same index.

The reason why i am asking its because, probably using Streams API, its possible to make it more generic, for any number of lists.

```
List<Double> listA = getListA();
List<Double> listB = getListB();
List<Double> listC = getListC();

int listsSize = listA.size();

    List<?> collect = IntStream.range(0, listsSize)
            .mapToObj(i -> listA.get(i) + listB.get(i) + list(C).get(i))
            .collect(toList());
```

thanks for any insight.

Comment: What else would you like to use it for - all `Number`s?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes you are right i just missed the obvious there, i edited it, the question is still valid for any number of lists, thanks

Comment: @sodik i mean for any number of lists, if i have lets say 100 lists, using  index from a range and get their values 100 times seems overkilling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
List<List<Double>> lists = ...;

// ensure all lists are same size, and get size
int[] sizes = lists.stream().mapToInt(List::size).distinct().toArray();
if (sizes.length != 1)
    throw ...
int size = sizes[0];

double[] sums =
    IntStream.range(0, size)
             .mapToDouble(i -> lists.stream().mapToDouble(list -> list.get(i)).sum())
             .toArray();
```

Comment: small typo, it should be `lists.stream().mapToInt(...)`, :-) Also couldn't you make this more performant with a `.distinct().limit(2)`, so that as soon as you find more than 2 different sizes you stop the computations?

Comment: @user2336315 Fixed typo.  Your suggestion of "limit" is OK, but frankly I wouldn't bother; the extra "cost" only shows up right before you are going to throw an exception anyway.  Small optimizations on the will-fail paths are rarely worth the additional complexity.